# ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Can access a folder in debug mode but not when I deploy it on IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-6

My MVC application was running fine(hosted on my local machine) but after restarting the system it is not able to access a network folder. However, in debug mode it is running fine but when I publish it it doesn't work.

> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\abc\xyz.txt' is denied.

The machine 'abc' is accessible to everyone on the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the app pool identity it's running under.  Ensure the identity has permissions to access the folder.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is that the folder gives write permissions to the Network Service user account or it will never work. Also make sure that the aspnet user has write permissions on the folder too.